# Same record is being inserted multiple times

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

Whenever I insert a record into my database, the record is being added 3 times.

```
try
{
   con.Open();

   object addedkey = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

   if ((addedkey != null && (addedkey != DBNull.Value)))
   {
      addedkey = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
   }

   added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   lblResult.Text = added.ToString() + " record opgeslagen.";
   lblResult.Text = addedkey.ToString();
}
```

But when I comment out `ExecuteScalar` and `ExecuteNonQuery` everything is working fine. So if I comment out one of the two, the record will be inserted twice.

This started happening after I added a delete button, which has nothing to do with the insert command.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It looks like you're executing the command three times.

Comment: can you post your cmd.executenonquery method , from your code i have an impression that you are overriding these functions as per custom needs.

Answer (score 4):

You are executing your insert every time that you run an **'Execute...()'** method on the command.  You run it three different times in your code, thus you insert 3x records.

```
    object addedkey = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //you run the insert command here
    if ((addedkey != null && (addedkey != DBNull.Value)))
    {
        addedkey = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());//you run the insert command here
    }
    added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//you run the insert command here
    lblResult.Text = added.ToString() + " record opgeslagen.";
    lblResult.Text = addedkey.ToString();
```

Comment: I did not have this problem before adding code for a delete command somewhere else.

Comment: can you post the query that you use?

Comment: string insertSQL;
            insertSQL = "INSERT INTO Deelnemer (";
            insertSQL += "Naam, Tussenvoegsel, Achternaam) ";
            insertSQL += "VALUES (";
            insertSQL += "@Naam, @Tussenvoegsel, @Achternaam); SELECT scope_identity(); ";

Comment: Yea your query is fine.  I'm not sure why your delete command would affect this, but your code is definitely running the insert query three times in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing 3 times. So really, you need to refactor code after the first execution.

You can change

```
addedkey = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

to this - this will prevent the 2nd execution:

```
addedkey = Convert.ToInt32(addedKey);
```

and change this:

```
added = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

to this - this will prevent the 3rd execution (this is assuming `added` is an int, and to be the return of your execution.

```
added = addedKey;
```

If `added` is actually a `boolean` then set it inside your `if` as it will have been validated by your `if` statement

I.E

```
{
    addedkey = Convert.ToInt32(addedKey);//you run the insert command here
    added = true;
}
```

Comment: My teacher told me to use executescalar to get the identity of the record just added, and executenonquery to display the rows affected, which i then have to display on the label. So ' added' is the rows affected and 'addedkey' is the identity of the record just created.

Comment: Then you need to change your select statement. This needs to return an ID, so assuming your return val is called `@id`,  add "`SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`" to your SQL statement.